# can i download excel files from jitter bit dataloader

Tags: data-loader

unable to download excel files from jitterbit dataloader
I am able to save files in .csv format but i want to save files in .xls(97-2003 format)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think JitterBit Data Loader supports XLS. Irrespective of that, you could always open the CSV in Excel and save it as a .XLS (97-2003 format)